# nginx no such file or directory

Tags: http, nginx, docker, artifactory

I have the following configuration in nginx

```
upstream artifactory_lb {
    server artifactoryserver.com:8081;
    server otherartifactoryserver.com:8081 backup;
}
```

Other config

```
rewrite ^/(v1|v2)/(.*) /api/docker/image-repo/$1/$2;
client_max_body_size 0;
chunked_transfer_encoding on;

location /v1 {
    allow all;
    proxy_read_timeout  900;
    proxy_pass_header   Server;
    proxy_cookie_path   ~*^/.* /;
    proxy_set_header    X-Artifactory-Override-Base-Url $http_x_forwarded_proto://$host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
    proxy_set_header    Host              $http_host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass          http://artifactory_lb; 
}
```

When I try to push an image I get a 405 - Not allowed error on the docker client while nginx logs show the following error

```
/usr/share/nginx/html/api/docker/image-repo/v1/_ping" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

How to configure nginx so that it pings the right repo location? Is this because the upstream server does not contain the repo?

UPDATE:
After making the following changes

```
location /v1 --> location /
proxy_pass http://artifactoryserver.com:8081/artifactory/
```

This error goes away but I get the following error on the docker client

```
Sending image list
Error: Status 403 trying to push repository ubuntu: "{\"error\": \"Unauthorized updating repository images\"}"
```

The docker daemon logs show

```
POST /v1.21/images/host:port/ubuntu/push?tag=
```

Does this mean it is hitting the repo and needs permissions to push images or does it mean the repo does not exist??

Comment: Your `rewrite` prevents the request getting as far as the `/v1` location. What exactly is the URI your client is presenting and what upstream URL do you expect it to be mapped to?

Comment: @user_mda I kindly suggest updating your previous questions instead of creating new ones which are all related to the same issue. It makes it hard to help and leaves an amount of unanswered questions.

Comment: @ drorb Thanks I answered those questions.

Comment: @RichardSmith: I am not sure what artifactory uri is created when I create repository. Shouldnt the rewrite replace everthing after v1 with /api/docker/image-repo//v1? I am following this https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Docker+Repositories

Comment: Updated the question after removing the /v1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unauthorized error was due to the fact that the docker version of the client did not support the v1 api that artifactory was configured to